# DSAS Can't Recognize Baseline and Shorelines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, digital-shoreline-analysis-system, shoreline

I have two shorelines and baseline which were created in accordance with the necessary rules such as attributes, coordinate system etc. All data in a personal geodatabase for DSAS analysis. The problem is that neither the shorelines nor the baseline appear in Set Default Parameters. Where am I making the mistake? [image: set default parameter]

Comment: Maybe the tool is not smart enough to use layers other than what they name in their [manual](https://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/DSAS/version4/images/pdf/DSASv4.pdf). Page 20 says "DSAS requires data to be in a projected coordinate system using meter units. "

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. My baseline shows up in the default parameters, but my shorelines do not. I tried both solutions (ticking the extensions box for DSAS and remaking the feature class in the mdb), but neither solved this issue. Has anyone else been able find a solution?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's an issue in your image. Make sure you haven't 'grouped' the data layers before using the DSAS tools. It wouldn't register my shoreline/baseline until I 'ungrouped' my files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and I tried both solutions (ticking the extensions box for DSAS and remaking the feature class in the mdb), but neither solved this issue.

I was able to find a solution after playing around with the sample data they provide. Their shoreline feature class was made up of "Polyline M" files, whereas mine were only polylines (you can find this under the shape field in the attribute table). I remade my feature class and made sure to click the box next to "Coordinates include M values". [image]

This fixed the problem of disappearing shoreline fc and allowed me to calculate the shorelines change. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, more or less... In my case the baseline was recognizable, but not the shorelines. For me, this was fixed simply by going to "Customize" --> "Extensions" and ticking the box next to the DSAS extension, that has been deactivated, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to create all features classes (fc) directly in the mdb. The first time I tried, I imported the fc from the GDB to the mdb, and still DSAS didn't recognize them.

Therefore, I created the fc in the mdb and started an edit session. I just selected the features in the previous fc and paste it in the new one. It worked!

Answer (score -1):

I tried all of the above and it didn't work. Instead I actually typed the baseline layer in and it eventually showed up!